# Scroll always on top when go back in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, safari, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular 1.3.2 and ui-router 0.2.15. I'm trying to get a regular scroll behavior in Safari, but it seems impossible.

Right now in Safari, when I go ahead the scroll places itself on top (right), but when I go back the scroll keep on top and it should retain the previous offset.

In Chrome it works perfectly, but in Safari it always gets the top position when i go back.

This is the code currently:

Index.html:

```
<section data-ui-view autoscroll="'true'"></section>
```

Init.js:

```
angular.module('mean').config(['$uiViewScrollProvider',
  function ($uiViewScrollProvider) {

    $uiViewScrollProvider.useAnchorScroll();

}]);
```

Why this wrong behavior in Safari? Is there any solution?

Thanks.